# Function overloading with object interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have the following snippet:

```js
interface props1{
    a: string,
    b: (i: string)=>void
}
interface props2{
    a: number,
    b: (i: number)=>void
}
function testFunction(props: props1): void;
function testFunction(props: props2): void;
function testFunction(props: props1 | props2){
    return props.b(props.a)
}
```

Currently, it is telling me that `Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`.

I expect it to pass `props.a` into `props.b`.

Comment: For something to be `props1 | props2` it would have to declare a `b` method whose first parameter was `string & number`, which can't exist. It seems like you need a _generic_, not an overload: https://tsplay.dev/wEx4VW.

Comment: This is essentially the minimal case of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended solution is to switch to generics as @jonrsharpe suggests.